# Sending post-install events to Branch.io

Tags: api, cordova, sdk, branch.io

Is it possible to send s2s events to branch from 3d party tracker? I see documentation for inapp events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Branchster here -

If you want to send S2S events, you can track it as a custom event using our API. For this the required attributes needed are

> name, OS, developer identity, and IDFA/AAID for ​APP. ​name, developer identity, and browser fingerprint for Browser.

Post that, you can make an API call with your custom events and the required attributes. You can reference the sample payload [here](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/tracking-commerce-content-lifecycle-and-custom-events#section-http-api-custom).